# How to add watermark to an image at the bottom right in PHP?

Tags: php, image, watermark

I am trying to add watermark to an image in PHP. I am using the below code that works fine. But I am facing challenges in the following ways.

```
<?php

 function watermark_image($target, $wtrmrk_file, $newcopy) {
    $watermark = imagecreatefrompng($wtrmrk_file);
    imagealphablending($watermark, false);
    imagesavealpha($watermark, true);
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
    $img_w = imagesx($img);
    $img_h = imagesy($img);
    $wtrmrk_w = imagesx($watermark);
    $wtrmrk_h = imagesy($watermark);
    imagecopy($img, $watermark, 500, 200, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    imagejpeg($img, $newcopy, 100);
    imagedestroy($img);
    imagedestroy($watermark);
}

watermark_image('1.jpg','assets/images/watermark.png', 'new_image_name.jpg');

exit();
?>
```

I am trying to achieve a code in which I can apply a watermark to any image on the bottom right side. with a fixed height and width of 150x150. I am trying from past 2 hours but no success in getting it accurately placed.

Does anybody has an idea? how to achieve it? It would be really very helpful.

Comment: What happens with this code?

Comment: And if you're actually using PHP 5.3, you should not be. It's been unsupported for years and years. PHP 7.1 is lowest version you should be using at this point.

Comment: I am using php 7.0 version, this code i picked up from my long back project. Can you help me out with an updated one?

Comment: @miken32 it places watermark in the center of image

Comment: Nothing in this code would have changed due to the PHP versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are placing the watermark image in the wrong location. It needs to be relative to the width and height of the source image, as well as the dimensions of the watermark image. This solves your problem:

```
  imagecopy($img, $watermark, $img_w - $wtrmrk_w, $img_h - $wtrmrk_h, 0, 0, $wtrmrk_w, $wtrmrk_h);
```

Comment: The above code worked perfect, it in the bottom right side, just confused how to et the height for 100x100 of that watermark

Comment: @AkshayShrivastav You already wrote the code to determine the dimensions of the watermark: ``$wtrmrk_w = imagesx($watermark); $wtrmrk_h = imagesy($watermark);`` I just used those values in my calculations.

If my response answered your question, please consider marking it as the solution. Thank you!

Comment: hi @kmoser, actually, I am facing a challenge that I want to make a 100x100 watermark on the bottom right of any image I upload, irrespective to size, I am facing a challenge in doing that. Could you help me with the updated code?

Comment: @AkshayShrivastav The code I provided will do exactly what you want. It uses the dimensions of the uploaded image, as well as the watermark, to place the watermark on the bottom right of the image, regardless of the size of the uploaded image or the watermark.

Comment: my current watermark is of 420 by 340 so it gets very large while putting a watermark, so I want to make it 100x100 is there any chance that I can do with code or I'll have to make the watermark size 100x100

Comment: You can rescale the watermark but be aware that when you rescale a 420x340 image to 100x100 it will distort: the watermark image will appear shorter/flatter. Is that really what you want?